# Bootstrap main container being left aligned only on mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Using `Bootstrap 3`, everything looks good on a browser, but on my mobile phone, the main container gets pressed to the left side of the screen and not centered the container. Why is it doing this?

[image: mobile]

[link to website](http://dev.glass-consultants.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `col-xs-offset-1` to your container class.

Comment: That messes up centering for the desktop.

Comment: u can add col-md-offset-* class for desktop

Comment: how do I do a class that sets for desktop only? can you show me an example? thanks!

Comment: you can have class like `<div class='col-md-* col-sm-* col-xs-*'>` This will make your div responsive for desktop,tablet and mobile.